# Obtener todas las filas en un char** de una llamada "Select names from tabletest" a una base de datos SQLITE3 con C

Tags: c, sqlite3

Estaba realizando un función que me retorna el name de todas las fila/rows de una base de datos con sql :

```
int The_Callback_id_list(void *a_param, int argc, char **argv, char **column){
    char** results = static_cast<char**>(a_param);
    int i = 0;
    while (i<argc)
    {
      results[i] = argv[i];
      i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void get_name_db(sqlite3 *db, char** idlist){
    char sql[1024];
    int resi;
    char *error = 0;
    sprintf(sql, "select name from tabletest;");
    resi = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, The_Callback_id_list, idlist, &error);
    if (resi != SQLITE_OK) {  
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", error);
          sqlite3_free(error);
        }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que el callback no funciona como yo esperaba, es como si se realizara una llamada por cada fila.

Por ejemplo mirando con gdb paro en el return 0 y veo que argc tiene valor 1 cuando tendría que tener 3 y que argv[0] solo tiene el primer nombre, le doy a continuar y vuelve al return y argv[0] tiene el del segundo pero claro results se esta borrando y solo se queda con la ultima.

**Osea que el problema es que por cada fila realiza una llamada al callback y por tanto me gustaría saber si alguien sabe de alguna manera de almacenar todos estos valores. Puesto que en la documentación que he encontrado no encuentro nada parecido. Gracias por la ayuda**

Answer (score 0):

Posible solución :

```
int The_Callback_id_list(void *a_param, int argc, char **argv, char **column){
char** results = static_cast<char**>(a_param);
int i = 0;
while (i<argc)
{
   if (results[i]=="0") {
        results[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(argv[0]));
        strcpy(results[i],argv[0]);
    }else
    {
        argc++;
        printf("leno");
        /* caso posición ocupada */
    }
    i++;
}
return 0;
```

}

la idea es antes de pasar el idlist idelist[i]=(char*)"0"; lleno de "0" de esta manera guardamos en memoria y podemos ir guardando donde este el "0" como si fuera la señal de vació.